# How can I tear-off top-level functions, getters, and setters

Tags: dart

How can I create tear-offs if I have a library like:

**main.dart**

```
int someFunc(int x, int y) => x * y;
int get val1 => 3;
int get val2 => 4;

main() {
  // create tear-offs of someFunc, val1, and val2 here
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When a library is imported with a prefix this is possible

**other_lib.dart**

```
int someFunc(int x, int y) => x * y;
int get val1 => 3;
int get val2 => 4;

class OtherClass {
  int someFunc(int x, int y) => x * y;
  int get val1 => 3;
  int get val2 => 4;
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'other_lib.dart' as o;

void main() {
  var _x = o#someFunc;
  var _v1 = o#val1;
  var _v2 = o#val2;

  print('_v1: ${_v1}, ${_v1()}');
  print('_v2: ${_v2}, ${_v2()}');
  print('_x: ${_x}, ${_x(_v1(), _v2())}');
}
```

but it also works in the same file

**main.dart**

```
import 'main.dart' as m;

int someFunc(int x, int y) => x * y;
int get val1 => 3;
int get val2 => 4;

void main() {
  var _x = m#someFunc;
  var _v1 = m#val1;
  var _v2 = m#val2;

  print('_v1: ${_v1}, ${_v1()}');
  print('_v2: ${_v2}, ${_v2()}');
  print('_x: ${_x}, ${_x(_v1(), _v2())}');
}
```

The analyzer doesn't yet recognize the syntax but the code runs fine in the VM (bleeding edge). See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24877

prints in both examples

> _v1: Closure: () => int from Function 'get:val1': static., 3
>   _v2: Closure: () => int from Function 'get:val2': static., 4
>   _x: Closure: (int, int) => int from Function 'someFunc': static., 12

Comment: According to the current language specification, this is a VM bug.

Comment: This is the opposite of the "It's not a bug, it's a feature!" => It's not a feature, it's a bug!" :D